# DocumentDB: How to better structure data for updates

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

So for example I have Collection of Documents like this:

```
{
   hotField1 : 0,
   hotField2 : "",
   coldField1 : 0,
...
   coldFieldN : ""
}
```

In this scope cold properties are written once, and accessed sometimes, hot properties are written and then fairly often accessed\updated (but in different use cases, it is not same sub-document or parts of same object).
Amount of documents is fairly huge (1M and more), size of hot data is at least ten times less than cold.

Since partial update is still most wanted yet not implemented feature, only way to update hotField1 is:

1. Request full document
2. Change either hotField1 or hotField2
3. Write back whole document

This is costly in terms of RUs, and doesn't scale so well.

**So the question is how to organize such data&calls in DocumentDB to minimize costs?**

Discovered alternatives:

1. <s>Obviously best: retrieve one property; change; update</s> - not yet.
2. Separate on two Collections, use stored procedures to retrieve from Main Collection then from Dictionary?
3. Put hotFields1-2 as subdocument `({ sub: {hf1:0, hf2:""}})` and somehow only update it? (I'm not sure if it is possible)

PS. C# in tags for client library we use. If it lacks smth its ok to use REST interface instead.

Comment: #3 is also not possible today. My first recommendation is to build it with the straight forward all-in-one-document approach and benchmark it. If it's not up to snuff, then tweak the allocated throughput parameter if using a partitioned collection or go to a higher S-level if not. If that's still not adequate, then consider a more complicated design of partitioning based upon how "hot" the field is. In my experience, engineer's assumptions about what will be fast and what will not are way off of reality. You need to experiment.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone, we already have working system on RDBMS so we have some amount of statistics already collected. Can you elaborate, what do you mean by more complicated design?

Comment: Just that splitting your data up by hot and cold fields is more work to build, maintain, and ramp up new developers. Why incur that cost before you know whether the simple all-in-one-document design is adequate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no exact "best" answer:

Your #2 choice will not work with stored procedures, since stored procedures are scoped to a collection.

Updating a subdocument (#3 choice) is no different than updating top-level properties - you are still retrieving, and re-writing, a document (a subdocument is just another property on the document).

While it may or may not reduce RU (you'd need to benchmark, as Larry pointed out in comments), you may choose to store your *hot* properties in a separate (smaller) document (or multiple smaller documents). With less properties, there would be less bandwidth consumed during updates, and less index updating. However, since you'd now be retrieving more than one document (possibly across multiple calls), you may find that this activity negates any RU savings from storing in a single document.

Note: There's nothing stopping you from storing these separate documents in the same collection (which then lets you approach the problem with a stored procedure, as you suggested in your #2 choice). You'll just need to create some type of property to help you identify different document types.

Comment: I spent some time thinking about whether it is a good idea to store separate documents. Apparently - no. I know for sure that partial updates are planned feature, but it's obviously isnt easy stuff. Isnt it much reasonable to first make special type of data - subdocument. So it will be not an ordinary JSON {} object, but small document in DocDB terms (ie with _etag, and other _ fields). I suppose it is possible for Concurrency Control, because just partial update will require something like _etag for each user added property of document. Then sub-document is valid for CC. What do you think?

Comment: I honestly don't understand your follow-up question, around not being an ordinary JSON object, nor do I understand how you concluded having separate documents (a technique employed very commonly) isn't a good idea, but... comments aren't for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL based on Documents replace the document once you change one or all properties.

In terms of cost, it is based on per collection basis.

So, if you have a DB with two collections in it and each with a performance tier of S1 i.e., $25/month.

$25 x 2 = $50

Case you need a better performance, and change one to S2 you'll be charged:

$50 + $25 = $75

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but has nice insight